# Download all files in firefox without prompt to open or save, 2019 edition

Tags: firefox, download

When downloading a file, Firefox pops up a window asking to confirm if the file should be saved or some other action should be taken.

I would like Firefox to download all files of any type without showing this window. I do not want to spell out automatic saving for each type of file individually (also, this checkbox does not even show up on my machine).

Firefox is configured to save all files to a download directory. I removed the option to *open* a file using `browser.download.forbid_open_with` but the window still appears, with the only ways to proceed being saving (by *OK*) or canceling.

Is there a way to, basically, have Firefox 'click' the *OK* automatically for me?

---

As for previous questions about this topic, I'm afraid these pertain to old/ancient versions of Firefox and the answers no longer apply. In particular that applies to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/848756/disable-open-with-option-on-firefox-downloads-force-firefox-to-always-save-al), [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1024213/firefox-download-all-file-types-without-prompt?noredirect=1&lq=1), [this](https://superuser.com/questions/192498/skipping-the-download-dialog-in-firefox) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/722295/firefox-keeps-asking-if-i-want-to-open-file-with-a-certain-program). (mimeTypes.rdf is no longer used, ASF is not supported with Firefox anymore, the DTA extension does not exist anymore, ContentDisposition is not the problem, and it should be general instead of a per-extension basis.)

Comment: What about using the add-on DownThemAll? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/downthemall/?src=search

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skipping the download dialog in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/192498/skipping-the-download-dialog-in-firefox). In spite of what the poster claims, some of the answers in this post still apply.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comments. I'm investigating your suggestions and will update when a clearer result is available.

Comment: @harrymc Can you clarify which answers you referred to? There is one that improves the situation (neverAsk.saveToDisk) but it does not work in all cases.

Comment: The accepted answer still works, even if one-by-one. `neverAsk.saveToDisk` still works for a list of MIME types. Alt+Click still works. I don't believe there is anything else.

Comment: @harrymc Hey, thanks. I don't like to specify this for every file type manually nor having to press alt (unreliable anyway), so these two are outside my scope. Best plan of action so far seems to be to add all mime types to `saveToDisk`.

Comment: @spikey_richie I'm a bit confused how to make DTA replace the native download without using context menus. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

From the `about:Config` list, try

> `browser.download.useDownloadDir`  Set this to `true`.

[image: browser.download.useDownloadDir screenshot]

This finally allows the downloaded file to silently be added to the WaterFox download list without any `Save As` prompt.

> The accepted answer still works, even if one-by-one. `neverAsk.saveToDisk` still works for a list of MIME types. Alt+Click still works. I don't believe there is anything else. – @harrymc

I tried many other answers from older posts, and none of them seemed to work. I was able to get rid of the initial dialog box (Open With or Save) by getting the MIME type listed with the help of a tool [Content-Type Fixer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/content-type-fixer/).   But the Save As dialog box just kept showing up...**Which is very annoying when you are downloading a lot of known files within the browser**

And no, I did not want to use download manager for these files, although those are helpful for other files.

Interestingly enough, the silent add to the download list was default behavior until about 4 months ago in WaterFox (Based on Mozilla browser).

I did not get to try `neverAsk.saveToDisk` because `browser.download.useDownloadDir` solved the problem.